# Jquery : Join duplicate information handling

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have ajax which fetches information from two different tables:

One table is *information* and other is *images*. There is unique information row which can join up to three rows from images table.

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT information.pointID, sName, sAddr, sPhone, iURL FROM information, images WHERE information.pointID = images.pointID AND placeID='$kraj';
```

I fetch the results with ajax as json.

**JS:**

```
...

var result='';
$.each(data, function(i,e) {
result += e.pointID+' '+e.sName+' '+e.iURL;
});

...
```

Lets say that there are three images for infomation 1 in the database.

My problem is that php fetches three rows, because there are three images for that selected information even though there is only one unique information row.

Here is the output i get with js after printing the result:

```
2 John 02151 John 02152 John 02153
```

What i want is to print basic information only once. Example:

```
2 John 02151 02152 02153
```

Comment: also add DISTICNT keyword before information.POINTID

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
SELECT a.pointID, DISTINCT a.sName, a.sAddr, a.sPhone, a.iURL FROM information as a, images as b WHERE a.pointID = b.pointID AND placeID='$kraj';
```

Hope this will helps you....

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a array like you need and sent that array to the JSON and generate the output.

The array would be like array('pointID','john',array(02151,02152,02153)). Looping through this would be easy.

```
data = ["point", "john", [9, 18, 3]]
result = data[0]+data[1];

$.each(data[2], function(i,e) {
  result += e;
});
```